GraphQL filtering on nested object retrieved from database (using Dataloaders?)
I have an SQL Database that I access via EntityFramework (C#). I want to expose the objects via a GraphQL API using the Hot Choclate framework. They are to be exposed pretty much without any changes.
The problematic part is that I want to make queries while Filtering on the properties of entities in another table.
From what I understand this is not possible if the relations are resolved by Dataloaders. Without Dataloaders, however, we're running straight into the n+1 problem.
Does anyone know a good way to resolve this?
It seems like it should be possible to translate such a grqphQL query into a combination of SELECT and JOIN. But I am no longer certain that is the case.
What I tried:
As example, I have these classes as entities
public class PersonEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("PersonEntity")]
    public List<MembershipEntity> Memberships { get; init; } = [ ];
}

public class MembershipEntity
{
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PersonEntity")]
    public string PersonId { get; init; }
    public PersonEntity Person { get; init; } = default!;
}

and these as graphQL API objects. For the relation, I use a dataloader as described in the tutorials.
public class Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public async Task<Membership[]> Memberships([Service] MembershipFromPersonIdLoader loader)
        => await loader.LoadAsync(Id, CancellationToken.None);
}

public class Membership
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string PersonId { get; init; }

    public async Task<Person> Person([Service] PersonByIdLoader loader)
    {
        return await loader.LoadAsync(PersonId, CancellationToken.None);
    }
}

Now I want to make a query to get Persons filtered by their membership's Status.
As far as I understand, this is not possible this way, since the Person query is resolved first, and then the DataLoader resolves the Memberships in a second query.
On the other hand, if I forego the Dataloader, the loading times and number of queries are naturally unacceptable.
I considered including transitive properties at the start of the query resolution, but that would result in loading all tables for every query.
Thank you in advance!
